# I don't see the option to create a new iOS Distribution Certificate

Tags: ios

I am on developer.apple.com/account trying to create a Distribution Certificate for my iOS app but I don't see the option. Earlier, I managed to create a Development one. I suspect there's something wrong with my account?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Benefits and Resources](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/) table. You cannot create `Distribution` certificates from a **free** Apple Developer account, which is yours apparently.

You need to enroll Apple Developer Program.

Comment: I have enrolled.

Comment: @skypower maybe a logout-login will fix that? Also make sure you have selected the correct team at the top right of Apple Developer Website.

Comment: Still no luck. I think I am gonna email Apple support. Thanks for help!

Comment: Turns out it was a role issue. I was a developer; now I became an admin and it worked!